# XPath - Proper syntax for retrieving attributes

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, attributes

I feel like I'm derping hard here, but I can I find the value of attribute2, based on attribute 1?

Take

```
<node attribute1="a" attribute2="b">Some Stuff</node>
```

I've tried this

```
//node[@attribute1=a]@content
```

with no success.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the XPath:

```
//node[@attribute1="a"]/@attribute2
```

This says to:

1. Find the node that has an attribute1 value of "a"
2. For the node found, return its attribute2 value